# ¿Cómo contar en tiempo real la longitud de un string?

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2, jtextfield

De ante mano, gracias por tomarse el tiempo de responder.

Estoy intentando realizar un textfiel **que reciba el código de un producto** registrado en una base de datos y que, **al llegar a determinada longitud, realice una acción**, para ser más específicos, que busque la información de ese producto y la devuelva en una tabla.

**Pero no tengo idea de cómo hacer que cuente en tiempo real la longitud de la cadena que se ingresa.**

¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

Actualmente estoy trabajando con NetBeans 8.2

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio y a leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Te recomiendo que coloques todo lo que ha intentado para mejorar el resultado de las respuestas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el evento **KeyReleased**

Ahora para obtener la longitud del texto ingresado lo hacemos de la siguiente manera.

```
jTextFielEjemplo.getText().length();
```

El cual si quieres que realice alguna acción cuando llegue a la longitud que quieres puede utilizar un **if**

```
if (jTextFieldEjemplo.getText().length() == longitud) {
            //acciones...
        }
```

Comment: Resulta que al dar clic derecho sobre el objeto, en la ventana diseño, aparece la opción evento>Key>Realeased.
Desde allí solo tuve que hacer lo que me dijiste.
Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

El texfield puede devolverte un String, solo deberias medir este String continuamente con un ActionListener posicionado en este JTextField.

Para que funcionase en tiempo real creo que lo mas recomendable seria hacer un hilo que coja este JTextField y vea su longitud, una vez vista que ejecute el código que desees, desconozco si hay algun método el cual al escribir un caracter lance un evento, o si el propio JTextField lo hace automaticamente, podrias buscar a cerca del funcionamiento en esta página:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html